# Обновить роуты в symfony2

Tags: symfony2, маршрутизация

Мне необходимо добавить новый роутинг в проекте, для этого я в файле routing.yml добавил новое правило. (скопировал и немного изменил текущие правила).

Но при переходе по ссылке я получаю 404 ошибку.

Нашел в папке app/cache/prod файл appProdUrlMatcher.php в котором, продублированы все роуты, но в немного ином виде. Если в этом файле прописать роуты, то все работает. Но насколько я понял этот файл генерируется автоматически. Если удалить этот файл или всю папку cache то перестает работать весь сайт.

Подскажите, как обновить эти роуты или как их правильно описать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновить кеш нужно.
И ты, видимо, работаешь не в dev environment. В дев окружении это происходит автоматически.

Comment: А как его очистить то?

Comment: из консоли php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod или удалить папки в  app/cache